# How to read an integer value in char type?

Tags: c, integer, char

I wanted to make a little experiment with scanf().
I wanted to read a small (<=255) integer from the user and store it in a char type.

I did:

```
char ch;
scanf("%d",&ch);
```

It works, but I want to satisfy the compiler and not to get this warning:

```
warning: format specifies type 'int *'
but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
scanf("%d",&ch);
```

Any idea?

Comment: `%d` means you are expecting an integer. Use `scanf("%c",&ch)` instead.

Comment: As Fractalism already commented, `%c` is used for `char` type. You can check [this website](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_input_and_output#Placeholder_codes) for the basics C place holders.

Comment: But OP does not want to read a character. For example wants to read `255` as a small integer (3 characters).

Comment: @WeatherVane exactly.

Comment: To read the range 0..255 you need `unsigned char c; scanf("%hhu", &c);`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to store a value 0 - 255, you should never use `char`. In fact you should never use `char` for the intention of storing anything but characters and strings. This is because that type has implementation-defined signedness: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

You could do:

```
unsigned char val;
scanf("%hhu", &val);
```

Although it is often best practice to use the portable types from `stdint.h`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>  // (actually includes stdint.h internally)

uint8_t val; 
scanf("%"SCNu8, &val);
```